# Mongoid assigning has_many embedded document array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a mongoid document (School) that has_many embedded documents (Students). Is there a way to do a direct assignment of a set of students, instead of doing a database call for each individual Student:

```
school.students << student1
school.students << student2
```

(many database calls)

vs.

```
school.students = [ student1, student2 ]
```

The problem is the second example seems to keep failing with an "Invalid Students" error.

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace of this "Invalid Students" exception. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is fixed in the latest versions of mongoid gems. A full gem update solved this.